# UISearchBarSearchContainerView is black

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

Why it is black?
In `viewDidLoad` I set this code:

```
var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
definesPresentationContext = true
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
searchController.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the style of the search bar.

It will look like

```
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = .blue
```

Here you can find how to change searchBar's appearance: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/1624281-searchbarstyle

Comment: This is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I set the app's "User Interface Style" to "Light" in info.plist. For some reason, the search bar doesn't appear to respect this setting and is rendering black when the device is in Dark Mode on iOS 13. I was able to force the search bar to render as white again by setting the search and navigation controllers' background colors.

```
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .white
navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
```